# PHP curl Soap request returning 404

Tags: php, curl, soap

I'm trying to use PHPs cURL and SOAP to perform a request to a public server, which then should respond with some image urls.

I managed to set it all up, the problem is, all I get in response is 404 - File or Directory not found. As far as I can see, I followed the service providers recipe for using SOAP. I am providing a "nobbnr" which is a product identifier, which should then be used to return the product images. Am I missing anything? The URL looks correct?

Their "recipe" is as follows:
http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/ProduktInfo.asmx?op=HentMedierForNobbNo
(look at soap 1.1)

My full PHP code is as follows:

```
 <?php
  $soap_request  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
  $soap_request .= "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n";
  $soap_request .= "  <soap:Body>\n";
  $soap_request .= "    <HentMedierForNobbNo xmlns=\"http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/\">\n";
  $soap_request .= "      <nobbnr>10871051</nobbnr>\n";
  $soap_request .= "    </HentMedierForNobbNo>\n";
  $soap_request .= "  </soap:Body>\n";
  $soap_request .= "</soap:Envelope>";

  $header = array(
    "POST /ProduktInfo.asmx HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no",
    "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
    "SOAPAction: \"http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/HentMedierForNobbNo\""
  );

  $soap_do = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/HentMedierForNobbNo" );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);

  $xml_result = curl_exec($soap_do);
  // check for errors
  if ($xml_result === false) {
  $error_occurred = true;
  }
  else {

      $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_result);

      print_r($xml);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct url address to service you're trying to reach is http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/ProduktInfo.asmx/HentMedierForNobbNo .

BTW: take a look at http://php.net//manual/pl/class.soapclient.php (or any other soap client like nuSoap). You don't have to create request XML manually. Also you'll get response object when invoking method.

EDIT:

As I mentioned above - try working on SoapClient:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://produktinfo.byggtjeneste.no/ProduktInfo.asmx?WSDL',
                array(
                    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                    'encoding' => 'utf-8',
                    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
                    'trace' => 1
                )
);
```

After that all you need to do is invoke proper method:

```
$params = new StdClass();
$params->nobbnr = 10871051;
var_dump($client->HentMedierForNobbNo($params));
```

Comment: Thanks! One step closer. However, now the response I get is:


`System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: text/xml; charset=utf-8.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()`

But according to the documentation link, content-type seems correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to make it work. I had to change the line `$params = new StdClass();` to `$params = array('nobbnr' => 123456);` for some reason, for it to work, but then I got the correct objects. In case anyone is wondering what to do with the resulting objects, I found this to be useful: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521545/retreiving-specific-values-from-a-soapclient-return-in-php)

Comment: yes, was my bad - 'HentMedierForNobbNo' object was unnecesary, it's wrapped by soap client (method name). So for object it'd look like this:
$params = new StdClass();
$params->nobbnr = 10871051; (edited the answer)